# swiping of listing screen from top to bottom and vice versa using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm workin on mobile app. I need swiping of listing screen from top to bottom and vice versa.
Please help me in swiping the screen from top to bottom and bottom to top using jquery mobile, as i dont know much about jquery. Thanks in advance. Below is my code

```
     <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
     <h1>Swipe</h1>
      <a href="home.html" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="back"  rel="external" data-iconpos="notext" >Refresh</a> </div>
      <form id="form1" >
       <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
      <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#Alerts" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn-active" >Year</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Activities" data-ajax="false" >Month</a></li>
       </ul>
       </div>

       <div data-role="content" id="Alerts" class="checkbox">
       <div class="content-primary" >
       <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="carat-r">
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>january</h2>
          </a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>


    <div data-role="content" id="Activities" class="checkbox">
    <div class="content-primary" >
      <ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" data-split-icon="carat-r" >
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h2>2012</h2>
          </a> </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
         </div>
       </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Clarify your question please, it's vague.

Comment: I want list items to swipe from top to bottom

Comment: You mean scroll? Wrap all content divs you have in a content div.

Comment: its touch based, when there are many list items we scroll the items for older items.